# How to force CMake to use a specific instance of Visual Studio/MSBuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I'm using CMake to build a project. We are trying to include in a repository all build tools (including third parties but also MSBuild), so that developper just has to checkout and build without having to install anything (and additionnaly, be sure they all use the same compiler).

So I:

- Installed `MSBuild` on my machine using the Microsoft installer, was installed in Program files...Now I can run `cmake "-GVisual Studio 17 2022"`
- Then I copied the installation folder content from Program files to a different place, let's call it `%MYFOLDER%`
- Then I uninstalled `MSBuild` using the Microsoft installer
- Now I'm trying to make the compilation work, so that it will work for other developers that did not run the installer on their machine

I load the vcvarsall.bat file from `%MYFOLDER%`. Then I run `cmake "-GVisual Studio 17 2022"`, but it reports:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 17 2022

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

Apperently, even if I loaded `vcvarsall.bat` from `%MYFOLDER%`, `CMake` does not find MSBuild.

Is there any `CMake` parameter that can be specified to tell `CMake` where to find the compiler?

Comment: "Then I copied the installation folder to a different place, let's call it `%MYFOLDER%`" - Do you mean **build** folder? Running `cmake` doesn't create *installation* folder, only the build one. And build folder isn't intended to be copied or moved elsewhere. BTW, if you actually run `cmake "-GVisual Studio 17 2022"` without additional arguments, then you are configured to perform **in-source** build, which is discouaraged.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. No, I copied the whole MSBuild folder from Program Files. I mean MSBuild installation folder.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the compiler works without being installed, there are various registry settings that need to be set

Comment: @AlanBirtles: You are probably right. I was expecting this to work smootly as there's vcvarsall.bat supposed to setup the environment...but it's probably not enough.

Comment: To avoid the developer installing Visual Studio, you will probably need a docker container or an equivalent that virtualizes an installation.